# Поочередная отправка сообщений по нажатию кнопки далее

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Имеется список машин в таком виде:

`[{'brand_id': ID бренда, 'car_name': 'название машины', 'year': год, 'price': цена, ... }]` который достается из базы данных.

[image: Пример клавиатуры для вывода]

Как при нажатии кнопки далее выводить следующий элемент из списка?
Есть мысль, что нужно куда-то сохранить количество нажатий на кнопку "далее" и выводить cars[i], где i - количество нажатий на кнопку, но может вы предложите лучший вариант решения задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать создать итератор списка, а затем переходить к следующему элементу с помощью встроенной функции `next()`.

```
cars_iterator = iter(cars)
next_car = next(cars_iterator)
```

Также не забудьте поработать с исключением **StopIteration**, которое может возникнуть при окончании элементов в итераторе.